# What is the correct verb conjugation in "voseo"?

Tags: verbos, conjugación, voseo

Following [the Wikipedia article on "voseo"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo), it is my understanding that the only differences are:

- replacement of 2nd singular with *vos*;
- replacement of 2nd plural with 3rd plural in Indicative, Imperative and Subjunctive moods.

Is that correct?
Can you provide correct full conjugation of all forms e.g. for *hablar*, *comer*, *vivir* and some reflexive and irregular verbs like:

```
yo hablo     nosotros hablamos
vos hablás   ustedes hablan
él habla     ellos hablan
```

Answer (score 4):

## Tiempo Verbal

-presente de indicativo

-pretérito imperfecto de indicativo o copretérito (voseo chileno)

-pretérito perfecto simple o pretérito de indicativo

-futuro de indicativo

-presente de subjuntivo

-pretérito imperfecto o pretérito de subjuntivo (voseo chileno)

-condicional o pospretérito (voseo chileno)

-imperativo

---

I will not make full conjugation ¬¬ :P

vos hablás

vos comés

vos vivís

---

The "voseo" is country dependent.
see http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=iOTUSehtID6mVONyGX

Example

## Argentina/Colombia

Vos hablaste

## Honduras

Vos hablastes

---

If you know the conjugation of vosotros (vos+otros), you know conjugate "vos" in "Español áurico" Golden age Spanish. Modern "vos" change "ái", "éi" by "á", "é" in most countries.

## Vosotros

Vosotros habláis

## Español Áurico

Vos habláis

## Español Moderno Voseante

Vos hablás

---

Some interesting phenoms exist, but they are not for this question. :P

Comment: thank you, do you know if vosotros is replaced with ustedes? can you provide full conjugation for a given verb?

Comment: el = ella = usted, el bebe, ella bebe, usted bebe. ellos = ellas = ustedes, ellos beben, ellas beben, ustedes beben. For simple communication you can learn conjugation for first person singular, third person singular, first person plural, third person plural.

Comment: I wanted to ask if 3rd plural is used for 2nd plural in Voseo: (nosotros bebemos, ustedes beben, ustedes beben) instead of usual (nosotros bebemos, vosotros bebéis, ustedes beben)

Comment: Usted and ustedes are 2nd person, (nosotros bebemos, ustedes beben, ellos beben). I do not think you should ask this in comments, make a new question.

Comment: sorry but usted and ustedes is the 3rd person singular and plural. the original question is exactly about my last comment: is my understanding correct that the only difference is replacement of 2nd singular with vos and 2nd plural with 3rd plural

Comment: from http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/usted: *vuestra merced (literally “your mercy”), an honorific style. Compare with the Portuguese você. usted (plural ustedes) second person formal; you (singular), Functionally, usted and ustedes are second person pronouns, but grammatically, the verbs they govern are conjugated in the third person.*

Answer (score 1):

in the wikipedia (the same link you provided) is the actual conjugation for "vos" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo#Conjugation_with_vos

for Parguayan Spanish:
conjugations for:

```
"hablar"
    yo       hablo 
    tu       hablas
    vos      hablás
    el       habla
    nosotros hablamos
    vosotros habláis
    ustedes  hablan
    ellos    hablan
"comer"
    yo       como
    tu       comes
    vos      comés
    el       come
    nosotros comemos
    vosotros coméis
    ellos    comen
"vivir"
    yo       vivo
    tu       vives
    vos      vivís
    el       vive
    nosotros vivimos
    vosotros vivís
    ellos    viven
```